# Cannot start container: [8] System error: exec format error

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm brand new to Stack Overflow and the world of containers, so hopefully my questions aren't too silly.

So first I will say that I'm aware that there are other questions similar to the one I'm asking, but I've tried the solutions in all of the ones I've found and they haven't worked for me. If there is another question out there that does have the answer, I'm really sorry for double-asking!

So, background info: I've got a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian, with docker freshly installed. I'm able to pull images down from repositories with no real issues. However, I can't run any of them. I always get the same error (the title of my question). Someone pointed out that it might be because there are mostly 64-bit images in the repositories and I'm running a 32-bit machine, which I thought was the problem. but then I pulled a 32-bit Debian image (the first thing I could find that was 32-bit) and tried to do docker run with the image ID. but it still comes up with that error.

What else may cause that error? Or maybe it's the fact that I'm doing it on a Pi...? Open to anything!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had similar issues when I tried to run Docker images on Rasperri Pi. Most of the Docker images are built for x86/x64 architecture. You need Docker-based apps packaged specifically for ARM to run on Raspberry Pi. Hypriot (Based on Debian) is one of the Raspberry Pi images that built for running latest Docker. Check it out [here](http://blog.hypriot.com/). They also have images specifically built for ARM. Search for hypriot on docker hub.You still may run these images with your current Docker installation, which I did not try.

Comment: Thanks, techtabu! That was the problem. I finally found some images designed for Pi and they were able to run. Thanks again!